# Peticiones anidadas ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Necesito realizar 2 peticiones `$.ajax()` anidadas, donde la segunda depende del valor entregada de la primera... en otras palabras el resultado de la primera entra en un bucle y por cada registro encontrado realiza una nueva petición
.
Algo como esto:

```
function mostrarInventarioOc() {

    var urlPrincipal = $("#urlPrincipal").val(); // url base
    var valor = $("#ocompra_id").val(); // id a buscar

    $.ajax({
        url: urlPrincipal+"detalle/buscarDetalleOC/"+valor+"/", 
        success:function(respuesta){
            var detalle = eval(respuesta);

                for (var i = 0; i < detalle.length; i++) {

                    $id = detalle[i]["id_pieza"]; // capturo id a buscar

                    $.ajax({
                        url: urlPrincipal+"bodega/stockBodega/"+id+"/",
                        success:function(result){
                            alert(result['cant_inventario']);
                            // aquí voy a imprimir los datos de la primera y       segunda petición
                        }
                    });
               }
           }
     });
 }
```

He leído que esto es mucho mas fácil con promise javascript, pero no he logrado hacerlo.

Answer (score 1):

Yo te recomendaría utilizar Promises, ya que el código en general puede quedar más limpio y legible. Te dejo una opción utilizando la librería Bluebird, quedaría algo así :

```js
function request(url){
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', url, true);
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    xhr.addEventListener("load", resolve.bind(null, xhr.responseText), false);
    xhr.addEventListener("error", reject, false);
  })
}


function mostrarInventarioOc() {

    var urlPrincipal = $("#urlPrincipal").val(); // url base
    var valor = $("#ocompra_id").val(); // id a buscar
  
    request(urlPrincipal+"detalle/buscarDetalleOC/"+valor+"/")
      .then(function(respuesta){
        var detalle = JSON.parse(respuesta);
        return Bluebird.all(
          respuesta.map(function(r){
            return request(urlPrincipal+"bodega/stockBodega/" + r['id_pieza']);
          })
        )
        .then(function(results){
          results.forEach(function(result){
            alert(result['cant_inventario']);
          });
        })
      })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/3.4.6/bluebird.core.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta!!!

Answer (score 1):

No lo veo tan complicado, solo creo que si lo quieres ver más facil, pon tu segunda petición en una función para que el código se vea mas entendible.

```
function mostrarInventarioOc() {
    var urlPrincipal = $("#urlPrincipal").val(); // url base
    var valor = $("#ocompra_id").val(); // id a buscar
    $.ajax({
        url: urlPrincipal+"detalle/buscarDetalleOC/"+valor+"/", 
        success:function(respuesta){
            var detalle = eval(respuesta);
                for (var i = 0; i < detalle.length; i++) {
                    mostrarDetalleInventario(detalle[i]["id_pieza"], respuesta);          
                }
           }
     });
 }
 function mostrarDetalleInventario(id,datosDelaPrimera){
    $.ajax({
               url: urlPrincipal+"bodega/stockBodega/"+id+"/",
               success:function(result){
               alert(result['cant_inventario']);
               // aquí voy a imprimir los datos de la primera y       segunda petición

                  }
           });
 }
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta!!!